# Find $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{a_{n-3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, supremum-and-infimum

Sequence $a_n$ is defined in the following way: $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 1$ and for $n > 3$: $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{a_{n-3}}$. Find $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $A = \{a_n  | n \in  \mathbb{N}\}$.

**Edit**: turns out finding out $\sup$ and $\inf$ is a hard task not only for me. I welcome **any interesting findings about this sequence** in the comments/answers. For examples improving obvious lower bound or providing an upper bound.

I've wrote a script in Python and it seems that $\inf A \approx 0.81722$ and $\sup A \approx 5.13748$. Also, the sequence itself behaves a bit like a sin function. I would like to hear ideas on how to find sup and inf. (I struggle even to show that $a_n$ is bounded from above).

Graph of $a_n$ values for $n=1,2,...,100$:
[image]

Comment: The [numerators](http://oeis.org/A185332) and [denominators](http://oeis.org/A185341) are both on OEIS, but there is not much information.

Comment: As given in the CROSSREFS, the sequence $a_n$ is denoted by $u_n$ in  [OEIS sequence A205303](https://oeis.org/A205303) which has more details.

Comment: As a brutally simplified toy version you could consider a(n) = 2 a(n-1)/a(n-2) which is periodic and can be solved explicitly. The simplification can be justified as follows: in the numerator we need something close in the index to a(n) and in the denominator something more remote.

Comment: Even showing that this sequence is bounded is hard...perhaps one should attempt showing that the sequence is bounded (I was unsuccessful).

Comment: It might be worth noticing that the "period" of $a_n$ is $\approx 8$, with the local infima moving by $10$, then $8$, then $8$. For example, we have local infima at $n= 697$, $707$, $715$, $723$, $733$, etc. There are exceptions to this, but the step size is always either $8$ or $10$ (at least for the first $5000$ or so $a_n$s). There are also some large-scale patterns that look much more overtly sinusoidal. See for instance these plots of the first $1000$, $1500$, and $2000$ $a_n$s: https://imgur.com/a/X3BjXEi

Comment: The local maxima also move by $10$ then $8$ then $8$, but this pattern seems to be broken more often, and unlike the local minima, the index of the maxima will sometimes move by $9$ (for instance, $4780$, $4788$, $4797$, $4806$, etc.)

Comment: I will think about this one

Answer (score 11):

(Too long to be in the comments)

This problem (and many related ones) showed up as part of my thesis (not yet finished), so perhaps I will share what I have found on this. This is not an answer, as I have yet to determine why even it is bounded, as many have observed to be quite difficult (at least to me) to show. But I have some qualitative observations, as well as variations of this (at the end).

Indeed, as you plot the sequence $a_n$ given by $a_{n+3}=\frac{a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ with $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$, we get
[image: n vs a_n]
(10000 terms of $a_n$.)

To me, it **appears** that $a_n$ is sampling two periodic functions, perhaps in an aliased way (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). So maybe $a_n=f(n)=f_1(n)+f_2(n)$ or $a_n=f(n)=\cases{f_1(n)\quad n\in I_1\\f_2(n)\quad n\in I_2}$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ have periods $T_1$ and $T_2$ that are irrational multiples (incommensurate) of each other.

To see this clearer, I decided to look at the plot of $(a_n,a_{n+1})$ instead, and we get:
[image: a_n vs a_{n+1}]

And we can also see this in 3d, by plotting $(a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2})$, we get

[image]

and from another perspective

[image]

Why do I think $f_1$ and $f_2$ have incommensurate periods? If their periods are rational multiples, then I would expect to get one closed orbit, instead of two disjoint ones. Further, one of the periods of $f_1$ and $f_2$ must be irrational, otherwise we should get finitely many different points, rather than two "**orbit filling**" set of points (perhaps one calls this quasi-periodic? I recall Strogatz uses similar terminology in his non-linear dynamics text).

An example of this: Consider $a_n=\sin(n)+\sin(1+\pi n)$, a sum of two periodic functions with incommensurate periods, then $(a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2})$ gives plot

[image]

So what we have at hand then is some **3rd-order nonlinear discrete dynamical system**, which I can only hope to learn more about. Similar to chaotic systems, the **deterministic** and **boundedness** nature are shared. Is there an analog "Lyapunov theory" for these discrete systems? I am not sure and would like to know more.

I have also looked at several variations:

(1) By adjusting the initial conditions $a_0,a_1,a_2$, they more or less affect the amplitudes, periods, and the vertical shifts of these functions. We still have two orbits.

(2) By considering $$a_{n+3}=\frac{a_{n+1}^{d}+a_{n+2}^{d}}{a_{n}}$$ with $a_{0}=a_{1}=a_{2}=1$ for some $d\ge 1$, they give similar behavior except the system seems to diverge without bound as $d>1.751$ experimentally. Here are some infima and suprema that I found experimentally:
$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
d & 1 & 1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.6 & 1.7 & 1.75 & \ge1.751\\
\inf a_{n}\le & 0.81722 & 0.81921 & 0.82185 & 0.82173 & 0.82341 & 0.82750 & 0.81064 & 0.87859 & 0.65700 & 0\\
\sup a_{n}\ge & 5.1376 & 6.1357 & 7.7257 & 10.590 & 16.578 & 33.253 & 115.30 & 1984.7 & 176274.73198 & \infty
\end{array}$
(The reason why I considered this variation was motivated from dynamical systems, where sometimes a parameter to the system will give a critical change in qualitative behavior. So $d$ has a criticality at around $1.751$ where the system is no longer bounded. Of course, this could also be due to computational limitations.)

(3) I have also looked at higher orders of the form $$a_{n+k}=\frac{a_{n+k-1}+\cdots+a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$, which all seems to give bounded sequence. The $k=4$ case experimentally I found $0.64568 \le a_n \le 17.22$.

This leads to two conjectures:

**Conjecture 34.** For a fixed integer $k\ge1$, the sequence $(a_{n})$ given recursively by $a_{n+k}=\frac{a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{n+k-1}}{a_{n}}$ is always bounded for any choice of initial conditions $a_{0},\ldots,a_{k-1}$, provided that the sequence is defined for all $n$.

and

**Conjecture 35.** For a fixed integer $k\ge1$, the sequence $(a_{n})$ given recursively by $a_{n+k}=\frac{a_{n+1}+\cdots+a_{n+k-1}}{a_{n}}$ with initial conditions $a_{0}=\cdots=a_{k-1}=1$ is eventually **not integral**.

The integrality of this sequence was part of the (many) motivations of looking at these sequences, as they are superficially similar to the **Somos sequences** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence).

I can show in a specific simple case where these **some** of these terms obey periodicity:

**Proposition 36.** Given the order k type 1 sequence given by $a_{n+k}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots+a_{n+k-1}}{a_{n}}$ with $a_{0}=-1$, and $a_{1},\ldots,a_{k-1}$ arbitrary. If ths seuqnece $a_{n}$ is defined for all n, then we have $a_{n}=-1$ for all $n$ that is a multiple of $k+1$.

**Proof**. Indeed, we have $a_{0}=-1$ and suppose $a_{j}=-1$ where $j$ is a multiple of $k+1$. Then note $$a_{j+k+1} =\frac{a_{j+2}+a_{j+3}+\cdots a_{j+k-1}+a_{j+k}}{a_{j+1}}
 =\frac{a_{j+2}+a_{j+3}+\cdots+a_{j+k-1}+\frac{a_{j+1}+\cdots a_{j+k-1}}{a_{j}}}{a_{j+1}}
 =\frac{a_{j+2}+a_{j+3}+\cdots+a_{j+k-1}-(a_{j+1}+\cdots a_{j+k-1})}{a_{j+1}}
 =\frac{-a_{j+1}}{a_{j+1}}=-1.$$

Though $a_{n}=-1$ for all n that is a multiple of $k+1$, the other terms need not observe periodicity. $\blacksquare$

If it is of interest to some of you: Some of these investigations are somewhat related to the study of **cluster algebras** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_algebra). A well known periodic sequence that arises from such "rational function" rule is the rule $$x_{n+1} = \frac{1+x_n}{x_{n-1}}$$ which has a perhaps surprising period of 5 (!). As it turns out, this "5" is no "accident", and is precisely the **Catalan number** "5". This particular "system" is a cluster algebra of rank 2. A rank 3 one has an orbit of 14, also a Catalan number.

In any case, perhaps this can start a conversation on this topic, as I am also stuck on this myself.

Comment: "Too long to be in the comments", haha. I'd say so! +1 for all the detail, and especially for the 2d and 3d plots. Good luck with the thesis ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Much thanks!

Comment: Good work! with the thesis @bonsoon

Comment: @bonsoon , some interesting observations on the numerators/denominators of the sequence: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324321/696105